# Float to 16bit, Stereo. Improve?

Tags: c#

So i am converting Float 32bit, to 16Bit in Stereo. And as i don´t fully understand it myself, it´s pretty much copy paste sadly.

But i wonder if it can be improved, in either quality or speed?
Not that any of them are terrible or anything.

```
    void SendWaloop(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] newArray16Bit = new byte[e.BytesRecorded / 2];
        short two;
        float value;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < e.BytesRecorded; i += 4, j += 2)
        {
            value = (BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i));
            two = (short)(value * short.MaxValue);

            newArray16Bit[j] = (byte)(two & 0xFF);
            newArray16Bit[j + 1] = (byte)((two >> 8) & 0xFF);
        }
        if (connect == true && MuteMic.Checked == false)
        {
            udpSend.Send(newArray16Bit, newArray16Bit.Length, otherPartyIP.Address.ToString(), 1500);
        }

    }
```

So well, it´s converting the buffer from 32bit to 16bit, and send´s it with UDP, nothing weird.

Though for me this looks very complex, but from what i understand, it´s just removing every 4  byte or something like that.

EDIT:

```
        unsafe
        {
            byte[] newArray16Bit = new byte[e.BytesRecorded / 2];
            fixed (byte* sourcePtr = e.Buffer)
            fixed (byte* targetPtr = newArray16Bit)
            {
                float* sourceTyped = (float*)sourcePtr;
                short* targetTyped = (short*)targetPtr;

                int count = e.BytesRecorded / 4;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    targetTyped[i] = (short)(sourceTyped[i] * short.MaxValue);
                }
            }

            if (connect == true && MuteMic.Checked == false)
            {
                udpSend.Send(newArray16Bit, newArray16Bit.Length, otherPartyIP.Address.ToString(), 1500);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably should ask this in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Guess so, but when i asked something like this last time, they said i shouldn´t ask it there. Well will ask there if no one answers here:)

Comment: Why short instead of int16_t? Since you're relying on it being 16 bits, you should make sure that it really is...

Comment: Read [their help](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), specifically the part under "I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?". I don't go there, so I can't really tell with certainty, but it looks like this belongs there. And if something fits somewhere else, it shouldn't be on [so].

Comment: @Dan it's C#, so [short](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx)  *is* guaranteed to be 16bit.

Comment: I'm very confused by your edit, which seems *mainly* to just copy in my answer ...? What is the edit meant to be telling us?

Comment: btw, in the edit: `value = (BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i));` is redundant; that is basically `sourceTyped[i]` - and you seem to be missing the `* short.MaxValue` from the original code (actually, `BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i)` is *wrong* in your edit, because `i` here is now 0, 1, 2, 3.... - not 0, 4, 8, 12 as per the original code

Comment: Sorry, the edit is supposed to have added your suggestion, into my code. But it´s not working as intended at all, so something is wrong.

But i have to add value = (BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i)), else the variable is unused. will ad the Two variable and short.max

Comment: Okay now i am confused, will add how it looks now though.

Comment: @user2587718 "But i have to add value = (BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i)), else the variable is unused. " - then *remove the variable*; honestly, `sourceTyped[i]` is doing what it needs to. Btw, I ran 64k of random data through your original implementation and my implementation, and the output is identical

Comment: Okay, well i tried, and something is probably wrong again.  Sorry, but i will add it to the code so you can see.

Comment: (whimper) what is with the `targetTyped[i] = (short)( sourceTyped[i]);` ? where did that come from? basically, that should be `targetTyped[i] = two;`, but you can simplify by removing the `two` variable, to get back to... *exactly what I posted in the first place*, which (I hate to say it): works *fine*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would need testing, but I would probably try with some `unsafe`:

```
fixed(byte* sourcePtr = e.Buffer)
fixed(byte* targetPtr = newArray16Bit)
{
    float* sourceTyped = (float*)sourcePtr;
    short* targetTyped = (short*)targetPtr;

    int count = e.BytesRecorded / 4;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        targetTyped[i] = (short)(sourceTyped[i] * short.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

---

To show that working identically:

```
using System;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] raw1 = new byte[64 * 1024];
        new Random(12345).NextBytes(raw1); // 64k of random data
        var raw2 = (byte[])raw1.Clone(); // just to rule out corruption
        var result1 = OriginalImplFromTopPost(raw1, raw1.Length - 20);
        var result2 = MyImpl(raw2, raw2.Length - 20);

        bool areSame = Convert.ToBase64String(result1) == Convert.ToBase64String(result2);
        Console.WriteLine(areSame); // True
    }

    public static unsafe byte[] MyImpl(byte[] source, int byteCount)
    {
        byte[] newArray16Bit = new byte[byteCount / 2];
        fixed (byte* sourcePtr = source)
        fixed (byte* targetPtr = newArray16Bit)
        {
            float* sourceTyped = (float*)sourcePtr;
            short* targetTyped = (short*)targetPtr;

            int count = byteCount / 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                targetTyped[i] = (short)(sourceTyped[i] * short.MaxValue);
            }
        }
        return newArray16Bit;
    }

    public static byte[] OriginalImplFromTopPost(byte[] source, int byteCount)
    {
        byte[] newArray16Bit = new byte[byteCount / 2];
        short two;
        float value;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < byteCount; i += 4, j += 2)
        {
            value = (BitConverter.ToSingle(source, i));
            two = (short)(value * short.MaxValue);

            newArray16Bit[j] = (byte)(two & 0xFF);
            newArray16Bit[j + 1] = (byte)((two >> 8) & 0xFF);
        }
        return newArray16Bit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don´t exactly understand how to implement it,  will add it in my post to show how i tried.

Comment: @user2587718 note that in the ral code, you only want to look at `e.BytesRecorded` amount of data - it is possible that `e.Buffer` is oversized. The only thing this changes is the cutoff. In fact, I'll edit.. it'll be easier than explaining...

Comment: Okay now it works! Please check it in my post one last time if i have done anything wrong, else, this is the answer:)  And, do i have to worry about "unsafe"?

Comment: @user2587718 no, you don't need to worry about `unsafe` *as long as you get the code right*, which I do ;p

Comment: Great, so finally i did it right, with Alot of help, much appreciation:) I guess this is a bit of a speed up, as Unsafe code with pointers and stuff is from my understand, faster if done right. Many Thanks!

Comment: @user2587718 with your edit, yes it looks like it is doing the right thing - and yes, that should be a tad faster.